# module Network.Socket isn't found in Idris

Tags: package, read-eval-print-loop, idris

I'm trying to import Socket in Idris in REPL:

```
Idris> :module Network.Socket
Can't find import Network/Socket
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Network.Socket` module is not in default available packages. Quick search shows me that `Network.Socket` is in `contrib` package:

https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/0.12/contrib_doc/docs/Network.Socket.html

Thus, you should run Idris REPL with specified package using `-p contrib` option:

```
$ idris -p contrib
Idris> :module Network.Socket
*Network/Socket> :t Socket
Socket : Type
```

Comment: `Network.Socket is in contri package:` -- where do you see that?

Comment: @Jodimoro I googled this module name. Found link that I posted in answer. This link contains `contrib` string. So I checked this library on github: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/tree/master/libs/contrib Anyway, there not so many libraries in Idris. With some ad-hoc search you can find package that contains desired module.